# Cannot find OpenPortal Portlet Container 2.x when creating a new server runtime environment in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, portlet, java-ee-6

I just started learning portlet and got stuck in the first place. I have installed JavaEE 6 SDK, Eclipse Helios and GlassFish Server 3.0.1. I also successfully configured OpenPortal Portlet Container (OPC) for GlassFish by running command:

```
java -jar portlet-container-configurator.jar
```

The problem come up when I wanted to create a new server runtime environment of OPC, there was no "OpenPortal Portlet Container 2.x" node like the tutorial said. I googled and found that I needed to install Eclipse Portal Pack but the link was dead.

Any suggestion, please?

Best Regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the .jar file on Internet. Thanks for watching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop portlets, I strongly recommend downloading Apache Pluto instead of using the open portlet container; you can download a version of Tomcat bundled with Pluto from their site: http://portals.apache.org/pluto

Actually, Pluto has a few quirks that you need to get past (for example, it wants you to run an 'assembly' step to add some entries to your web.xml) but once you do it is probably the best way.  You could also try Liferay or JBoss' GateIn for development, but if you are ultimately targeting a vendor supplied platform like WebSphere, you might find that these actually have features that aren't as portable, whereas Pluto is really just a simple implementation of the portlet spec.